# Display different values of one enumerator list into different sub menu of menu list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a enum as follows  [It is just prototype]

```
public enum class Alphabets
    {
        None=0,
        A, E, I, O, U,
        B, C, D, F, G,
        Noun, Adj, Verb,            
        NoSign
    };
```

I want to display this enum contents into menu item such that,
Main menu "English" contains sublist as Vowels, Letters, Grammer
and these sublist contains element as follows,

English
- Vowels - A, E, I, O, U
- Letters - B, C, D, F, G,
- Grammer - Noun, Adj, Verb

Is it possible to have one enum and sort it across different sub menu of menu list or different menu list?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense - why not just have different Enums for each logically different thing?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - You are right. But it is just prototype. Actually, enum is  GIVEN in header file & enum list contains hundreds of  elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can notate each enum with a Display GroupName then when you enumerate through them, get that GroupName and sort accordingly

I use these extension methods to get the values

```
    //gets the attributes from the enum
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var type = value.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
        var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return (T)attributes[0];
    }

    //this will pull the DisplayGroup from the Display attribute
    public static string DisplayGroup(this Enum value)
    {
        var attribute = value.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.GroupName;
    }

    //enum decoration looks like
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [Display(GroupName = "MyGroupName")]
        AnEnum
    }

    //pull the group name like
    var groupName = MyEnum.AnEnum.DisplayGroup();
    //Assert.IsTrue(groupName.Equals("MyGroupName");
```

Comment: [Display(GroupName = "MyGroupName")]  -- This is not working in C++/CLI.
Error : Expected an identifier......

Comment: C++/CLI?  Though this was for c#.